# tabs don't change using sliding (with the finger ) on the IOS (works on android) MAUI

Tags: ios, maui

I have a program that uses tabs,
when I am running it on Android sliding between the tabs using the finger works. In IOS not

```
  <Tab>
    <ShellContent
        Title="tab1"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

    <ShellContent
        Title="tab2"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:SecondaryPage}"
        Route="SecondaryPage" />
</Tab>
```

Comment: AFAIK this is standard Android behavior, but not standard on iOS

Comment: is there any way to add it to the IOS?

Comment: For me, it does not slide for Android either. Did you do something else that might make it work for Android? Or could it depend on Android version?

Comment: <TabBar> doesn't work in Android  if you use <Tab> it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported on Maui iOS yet, you can raise a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new?assignees=&labels=proposal%2Fopen%2Ct%2Fenhancement&projects=&template=feature-request.yml) on Github.

However, if these tabs are bottom tabs on Shell like below. You can achieve it via adding swipe gesture to slide between the tabs using the finger on iOS.

```
<TabBar>
      <Tab Title="Domestic"
            Icon="paw.png">
           <ShellContent Title="Cats"
                         Icon="cat.png"
                         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
      </Tab>

      <ShellContent Title="Dogs"
                         Icon="dog.png"
                         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />

      <ShellContent Title="Monkeys"
                     Icon="monkey.png"
                     ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
</TabBar>
```

Below are the detailed steps:

1. Create the platform-specific implementation file `CustomShellRender.cs` under `Platform/iOS`:

```
   public class CustomShellRender : ShellRenderer 
   {
          public CustomShellRender()
          {
          }

        protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new CustomTabbarAppearance();
        }
    }

    public class CustomTabbarAppearance : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker {

        public void Dispose() { }
        public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller) { }
        public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance) {

            UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer((gesture) =>
            {
                if (controller.SelectedIndex > 0) {
                    controller.SelectedIndex--;
                }
            });

            swipeRight.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
            controller.View.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeRight);

            UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeLeft = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer((gesture) =>
            {
                if (controller.SelectedIndex < controller.ViewControllers.Count() - 1)
                {
                    controller.SelectedIndex++;
                }
            });

            swipeLeft.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left;
            controller.View.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft);
        }
        public void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller) { }
    }
```

2. Then register our handlers like below in the `MauiProgram.cs`:

```
        .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers=> { 
#if IOS
          handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(CustomShellRender));
#endif }) ;
```

Comment: thank you, Alexander, 
I will try it :-)